# postgresql create table of days per month

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm trying to write a script which returns a list of months with the number of days in the month. It references this table

```
 CREATE TABLE generic.time_series_only (measurementdatetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL)
```

which is just a chronological time series (and very useful when joining tables of data with gaps in different places, but you want an unbroken timeseries as your output, maybe there's a smarter way to do that but I haven't found it yet).

```
SELECT date_part('year'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime) AS
    measyear,
         date_part('month'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime) AS
           measmonth,
         date_trunc('month'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime) +
           '1 mon'::interval - date_trunc('month'::text,
           time_series_only.measurementdatetime) AS days_in_month
  FROM generic.time_series_only
  GROUP BY date_part('year'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime),
           date_part('month'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime)
  ORDER BY date_part('year'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime),
           date_part('month'::text, time_series_only.measurementdatetime);
```

But I get this error:

```
  ERROR:  column "time_series_only.measurementdatetime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I can't put this column in the GROUP BY clause because then I'd get a result for every single entry in the time_series_only table, and I can't figure a way to get the same result using an aggregate function? Any suggestions very welcome :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on` a pair (year, month). You can replace the `time_series_only` table with the function `generate_series()` , e.g.:

```
select distinct on (date_part('year', d), date_part('month', d))
    date_part('year', d) as year, 
    date_part('month', d) as month, 
    date_part('day', d) as days_in_month
from 
    generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, '2016-12-31'::date, '1d'::interval) d
order by 1, 2, 3 desc;

 year | month | days_in_month 
------+-------+---------------
 2016 |     1 |            31
 2016 |     2 |            29
 2016 |     3 |            31
 2016 |     4 |            30
 2016 |     5 |            31
 2016 |     6 |            30
 2016 |     7 |            31
 2016 |     8 |            31
 2016 |     9 |            30
 2016 |    10 |            31
 2016 |    11 |            30
 2016 |    12 |            31
(12 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

you not using generate_series?.. like here:

```
vao=# with pre as (select generate_series('2016-01-01','2017-03-31','1 day'::interval) g) select distinct
extract('year' from g), extract('month' from g), count(1) over (partition by date_trunc('month',g)) from pre order by 1,2;
 date_part | date_part | count
-----------+-----------+-------
      2016 |         1 |    31
      2016 |         2 |    29
      2016 |         3 |    31
      2016 |         4 |    30
      2016 |         5 |    31
      2016 |         6 |    30
      2016 |         7 |    31
      2016 |         8 |    31
      2016 |         9 |    30
      2016 |        10 |    31
      2016 |        11 |    30
      2016 |        12 |    31
      2017 |         1 |    31
      2017 |         2 |    28
      2017 |         3 |    31
(15 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one has better performance since it generates only the last day for each month and consequently does not need aggregation:

```
select
    date_part('year', d) as year, 
    date_part('month', d) as month, 
    date_part('day', d) as days_in_month
from 
    generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01', '1 month') gs(gsd)
    cross join lateral
    (select gsd + interval '1 month - 1 day') d(d)
order by 1, 2;

 year | month | days_in_month 
------+-------+---------------
 2016 |     1 |            31
 2016 |     2 |            29
 2016 |     3 |            31
 2016 |     4 |            30
 2016 |     5 |            31
 2016 |     6 |            30
 2016 |     7 |            31
 2016 |     8 |            31
 2016 |     9 |            30
 2016 |    10 |            31
 2016 |    11 |            30
 2016 |    12 |            31
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, using CTEs for a bit more readability, IMHO (this example generating months and datas for next threee full months following the calendar month of current_date)

```
WITH series AS (                                                                                                                                                   
  SELECT generate_series ( 
    date_trunc ('month', date_trunc('day', now()) + interval '1 month'), 
    date_trunc('day', now() + interval '4 months'), '1d'::interval
  ) AS day                                                                                                                                                                               )                                                                                                                                                                                 SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_part('year', series.day),     date_part('month', series.day))
  date_part('year', series.day) as year,
  date_part('month', series.day) as month,
  date_part('day', series.day) as days_in_month
FROM series
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3 desc LIMIT 3;

 year | month | days_in_month 
------+-------+---------------
 2021 |     1 |            31
 2021 |     2 |            28
 2021 |     3 |            31
```